# SSRS Report Custom Prompt Layout

Tags: sql-server-2008, layout, reporting-services, bids

Is it possible with business intelligence development studio to create an SSRS report and easily customize the way that the prompt fields are laid out (mainly the location)? It looked like it defaults to grouping them horizontally, I would want to perhaps group the prompts into section.

I'm just getting into using SSRS so my knowledge is limited. I've read a few tutorials but haven't found an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to change some of the styles and images, but I don't know if you can change the actual layout.  It may be possible to do it with the style sheet, as it looks like the UI is generated from a dll.

Start here and poke around:
\ServerName\c$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportManager\

Styles\ReportingServices.css should let you do some formatting changes - font size, layout, colors, etc.

Styles\RSWebParts.css should let you change more formatting.

MS was even considerate enough to comment thoroughly.  I would just start messing around with the "View Source" in your dev environment.  See what classes are assigned to the controls you would like to move.

Good luck - could actually be fun.